# Can I bulk delete one node property for all nodes?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb, opencypher

I got the data model that has three nodes that are connected with three relations.

[This is my data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9BTI.png)

By looking at the model it makes no sense to me to store both 2 and 3 letter codes for each Country so I would like to delete all 2 letter ISO codes from countries.

I've tried to run the following code but I get no return.

```
  MATCH (n:Country)
  WHERE exists(n.iso_2_code)
  REMOVE n.iso_2_code
  RETURN n
```

What should I do? Is there an alternative way?

Comment: Your query looks correct from an openCypher perspective. If you take out the `REMOVE` line from the query do you get any results? I'm just wondering if the `MATCH` is actually finding anything.

Comment: I've created a new Memgraph install. This time I've used Memgraph Cloud, and I got an error "Query failed: Function 'EXISTS' doesn't exist.". I kept on digging and I found in the documentation that Memgraph uses another way to to this (https://memgraph.com/docs/cypher-manual/differences): n.property IS NOT NULL.

Comment: Good to know - glad you found a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Memgraph documentation](https://memgraph.com/docs/cypher-manual/differences) `exists` is not supported and one should use `n.property IS NOT NULL`.

The correct code is:

```
 MATCH (n:Country)
 WHERE n.iso_2_code IS NOT NULL
 REMOVE n.iso_2_code
 RETURN n
```